# PostgreSQL/Python - Get last N rows no repeated

Tags: python, postgresql

is there any way I can do this?

---

Eg. If my table contains the following elements:

```
id | username | profile_photo
---+----------+--------------
 1 |     juan | urlphoto/juan
 2 |   nestor | urlphoto/nestor
 3 |    pablo | urlphoto/pablo
 4 |    pablo | urlphoto/pablo
```

And, I want get last 2(two) rows should get:

```
id 2 -> nestor | urlphoto/nestor
id 3 -> pablo  | urlphoto/pablo
```

---

Thanks for your time.

SOLUTION:

The solution is to insert an item if not already in the first n elements

```
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras, json
db = psycopg2.connect("")

cursor = db.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT n;")
row = [item['user_id'] for item in cursor.fetchall()]

if not user_id in row:
    cursor.execute("INSERT..")
    db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT id, username, profile_photo
FROM (select min(id), username, profile_photo FROM table
      GROUP BY username, profile_photo) tmp ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the final row order, here you go

```
SELECT min(id), username, profile_photo 
FROM oh_my_table
GROUP BY username, profile_photo
ORDER BY min(id) DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe what constitutes a duplicate row (in your example nothing is repeated, because all rows are unique thanks to id), but I'm assuming you want the rows to be distinct on all columns except id and you don't care which id from a few possible duplicates it might be.

Let's start with some test data:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE profile_photos (id int, username text, profile_photo text);
Time: 417.014 ms

INSERT INTO profile_photos
SELECT g.id, r.username, 'urlphoto/' || r.username
FROM generate_series(1, 10000000) g (id)
CROSS JOIN substr(md5(g.id::text), 0, 8) r (username);
INSERT 0 10000000
Time: 24497.335 ms
```

I'll test two possible solutions, and these are two indexes for each solution:

```
CREATE INDEX id_btree ON profile_photos USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 8139.347 ms

CREATE INDEX username_profile_photo_id_btree ON profile_photos USING btree (username, profile_photo, id DESC);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 81667.411 ms

VACUUM ANALYZE profile_photos;
VACUUM
Time: 1338.034 ms
```

So the first solution is the one given by Sami and Clément (their queries are essentially the same):

```
SELECT min(id), username, profile_photo 
FROM profile_photos
GROUP BY username, profile_photo
ORDER BY min(id) DESC 
LIMIT 2;

   min    | username |  profile_photo   
----------+----------+------------------
 10000000 | d1ca3aa  | urlphoto/d1ca3aa
  9999999 | 283f427  | urlphoto/283f427
(2 rows)
Time: 5088.611 ms
```

The result looks right, but this query can yield undesired results if any of those users have posted a profile photo before. Let's emulate that:

```
UPDATE profile_photos
SET (username, profile_photo) = ('d1ca3aa', 'urlphoto/d1ca3aa')
WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE 1
Time: 1.313 ms

SELECT min(id), username, profile_photo 
FROM profile_photos
GROUP BY username, profile_photo
ORDER BY min(id) DESC 
LIMIT 2;

   min   | username |  profile_photo   
---------+----------+------------------
 9999999 | 283f427  | urlphoto/283f427
 9999998 | facf1f3  | urlphoto/facf1f3
(2 rows)
Time: 5032.213 ms
```

So the query is ignoring anything newer the user might have added. It doesn't look like what you want, so I suggest replacing min(id) with max(id):

```
SELECT max(id), username, profile_photo 
FROM profile_photos
GROUP BY username, profile_photo
ORDER BY max(id) DESC 
LIMIT 2;

   max    | username |  profile_photo   
----------+----------+------------------
 10000000 | d1ca3aa  | urlphoto/d1ca3aa
  9999999 | 283f427  | urlphoto/283f427
(2 rows)
Time: 5068.507 ms
```

Right, but it looks slow. The query plan is:

```
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=655369.97..655369.98 rows=2 width=29) (actual time=6215.284..6215.285 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=655369.97..678809.36 rows=9375755 width=29) (actual time=6215.282..6215.282 rows=2 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (max(id))
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..561612.42 rows=9375755 width=29) (actual time=0.104..4945.534 rows=9816449 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using username_profile_photo_id_btree on profile_photos  (cost=0.56..392855.43 rows=9999925 width=29) (actual time=0.089..1849.036 rows=10000000 loops=1)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 6215.344 ms
(8 rows)
```

The thing to notice here is that there's no legitimate use of an aggregate that would entail a GROUP BY: the GROUP BY in this case is used to filter out duplicates and the only aggregate here is a work-around to pick any one of them. Postgres has an extension that lets you discard duplicates on a set of columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM (    
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (username, profile_photo) *
    FROM profile_photos
) X
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2;

    id    | username |  profile_photo   
----------+----------+------------------
 10000000 | d1ca3aa  | urlphoto/d1ca3aa
  9999999 | 283f427  | urlphoto/283f427
(2 rows)
Time: 3779.723 ms
```

That's a bit faster, and here's why:

```
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=630370.16..630370.17 rows=2 width=29) (actual time=4921.031..4921.031 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=630370.16..653809.55 rows=9375755 width=29) (actual time=4921.030..4921.030 rows=2 loops=1)
         Sort Key: profile_photos.id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Unique  (cost=0.56..442855.06 rows=9375755 width=29) (actual time=0.114..4220.410 rows=9816449 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using username_profile_photo_id_btree on profile_photos  (cost=0.56..392855.43 rows=9999925 width=29) (actual time=0.111..2040.601 rows=10000000 loops=1)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 4921.081 ms
(8 rows)
```

What if we could somehow fetch the last row with a simple ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, and look for another row from the end of the table, that wouldn't be a duplicate?

```
WITH first AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM profile_photos
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT *
FROM first
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM profile_photos p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM first
    WHERE (first.username, first.profile_photo) <> (p.username, p.profile_photo))
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1);

    id    | username |  profile_photo   
----------+----------+------------------
 10000000 | d1ca3aa  | urlphoto/d1ca3aa
  9999999 | 283f427  | urlphoto/283f427
(2 rows)
Time: 1.217 ms
```

This is very fast, but hand-tailored to yield only two rows. Let's replace it with something more "automatic":

```
WITH RECURSIVE last (id, username, profile_photo, a) AS (
    (SELECT id, username, profile_photo, ARRAY[ROW(username, profile_photo)] a
    FROM profile_photos
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT older.id, older.username, older.profile_photo, last.a || ROW(older.username, older.profile_photo)
    FROM last
    JOIN profile_photos older ON last.id > older.id AND NOT ROW(older.username, older.profile_photo) = ANY(last.a)
    WHERE array_length(a, 1) < 10
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1)
)
SELECT id, username, profile_photo
FROM last;

    id    | username |  profile_photo   
----------+----------+------------------
 10000000 | d1ca3aa  | urlphoto/d1ca3aa
  9999999 | 283f427  | urlphoto/283f427
  9999998 | facf1f3  | urlphoto/facf1f3
  9999997 | 305ebab  | urlphoto/305ebab
  9999996 | 74ab43a  | urlphoto/74ab43a
  9999995 | 23f2458  | urlphoto/23f2458
  9999994 | 6b465af  | urlphoto/6b465af
  9999993 | 33ee85a  | urlphoto/33ee85a
  9999992 | c0b9ef4  | urlphoto/c0b9ef4
  9999991 | b63d5bf  | urlphoto/b63d5bf
(10 rows)
Time: 2706.837 ms
```

This is faster than the previous queries, but as you can see in the query plan below, for each yielded row it has to scan the index on id.

```
                                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CTE Scan on last  (cost=6.52..6.74 rows=11 width=68) (actual time=0.104..4439.807 rows=10 loops=1)
   CTE last
     ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.43..6.52 rows=11 width=61) (actual time=0.098..4439.780 rows=10 loops=1)
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.47 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.095..0.095 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Index Scan Backward using id_btree on profile_photos  (cost=0.43..333219.47 rows=9999869 width=29) (actual time=0.093..0.093 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.58 rows=1 width=61) (actual time=443.965..443.966 rows=1 loops=10)
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..1406983.38 rows=9510977 width=61) (actual time=443.964..443.964 rows=1 loops=10)
                       Join Filter: ((last_1.id > older.id) AND (ROW(older.username, older.profile_photo) <> ALL (last_1.a)))
                       Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using id_btree on profile_photos older  (cost=0.43..333219.47 rows=9999869 width=29) (actual time=0.008..167.755 rows=1000010 loops=10)
                       ->  WorkTable Scan on last last_1  (cost=0.00..0.25 rows=3 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=10000102)
                             Filter: (array_length(a, 1) < 10)
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Total runtime: 4439.907 ms
(14 rows)
```

Since Postgres 9.3 there's a new JOIN type available, LATERAL JOIN. It lets you make a join decision at a row level (i.e. it works "for each row"). We can use that to implement following logic: "for as long as we don't have N rows, for each of the generated rows see if there's an older row than the last one and if there is, add that row to the generated result".

```
WITH RECURSIVE last (id, username, profile_photo, a) AS (
    (SELECT id, username, profile_photo, ARRAY[ROW(username, profile_photo)] a
    FROM profile_photos
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT older.id, older.username, older.profile_photo, last.a || ROW(older.username, older.profile_photo)
    FROM last
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT *
        FROM profile_photos older
        WHERE last.id > older.id AND NOT ROW(older.username, older.profile_photo) = ANY(last.a)
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) older
    WHERE array_length(a, 1) < 10
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1)
)
SELECT id, username, profile_photo
FROM last;

    id    | username |  profile_photo   
----------+----------+------------------
 10000000 | d1ca3aa  | urlphoto/d1ca3aa
  9999999 | 283f427  | urlphoto/283f427
  9999998 | facf1f3  | urlphoto/facf1f3
  9999997 | 305ebab  | urlphoto/305ebab
  9999996 | 74ab43a  | urlphoto/74ab43a
  9999995 | 23f2458  | urlphoto/23f2458
  9999994 | 6b465af  | urlphoto/6b465af
  9999993 | 33ee85a  | urlphoto/33ee85a
  9999992 | c0b9ef4  | urlphoto/c0b9ef4
  9999991 | b63d5bf  | urlphoto/b63d5bf
(10 rows)
Time: 1.966 ms
```

Now that's fast... until N is too big.

```
                                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CTE Scan on last  (cost=18.61..18.83 rows=11 width=68) (actual time=0.074..0.359 rows=10 loops=1)
   CTE last
     ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.43..18.61 rows=11 width=61) (actual time=0.070..0.346 rows=10 loops=1)
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.47 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.067..0.068 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Index Scan Backward using id_btree on profile_photos  (cost=0.43..333219.47 rows=9999869 width=29) (actual time=0.065..0.065 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Limit  (cost=1.79..1.79 rows=1 width=61) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=10)
                 ->  Sort  (cost=1.79..1.80 rows=3 width=61) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=10)
                       Sort Key: older.id
                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..1.77 rows=3 width=61) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=10)
                             ->  WorkTable Scan on last last_1  (cost=0.00..0.25 rows=3 width=36) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=10)
                                   Filter: (array_length(a, 1) < 10)
                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                             ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.49 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=9)
                                   ->  Index Scan Backward using id_btree on profile_photos older  (cost=0.43..161076.14 rows=3170326 width=29) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=9)
                                         Index Cond: (last_1.id > id)
                                         Filter: (ROW(username, profile_photo) <> ALL (last_1.a))
                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 0
 Total runtime: 0.439 ms
(19 rows)
```